# When a sigma algebra is closed under countable intersection?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

In "Measure Theory and Probability Theory" by Krishna and Soumendra pag. 43 there is the following passage.

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and $\{f_n\}$ a
>   sequence of functions such that $f_n:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
>   a measurable function for each $n\ge 1$.
>
> Let $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty, -\infty\}$ be the
>   extended real line and
>   $\mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})=\sigma\left<\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})
>  \cup \{+\infty\} \cup \{-\infty\}\right>$  be the extended Borel
>   $\sigma$-algebra on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$.
>
> Define $g= \Omega \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}} $ as the supremum
>   pointwise $g=sup_{n \ge 1}f_n$.

Then the book says that for show $g$ being measurable is enough to show that $g^{-1}((-\infty, r]) \in \mathcal{F}$ for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus it continues with the proof below.

> $(-\infty, r] = \{\omega: g(\omega) \ge r \} = \\
>  \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \{\omega: f_n(\omega) \ge r \}=\\
>  \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n^{-1}((-\infty, r]) \in \mathcal{F} $
>
> since $f_n^{-1}((-\infty, r]) \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $n \ge 1$ by
>   the measurability of $f_n$.

What assures us that the countbale intersection of those sets is in $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $A_n\in \Sigma$ for all $n$ then $\cap A_n \in \Sigma$. This is in the definition (closure under countable set operations).

Comment: @NapD.Lover The definition of $\sigma$-algebra usually mentions just one of the countable set operations, not both, and then, if I had to generalize, it's usually $\bigcup$ not $\bigcap$.

Comment: @BrianO yes of course, I agree. More precisely I could have written “this is in the theorem characterizing $\sigma$-algebras, as a routine application of DeMorgan’s law to the definition”.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Well, now you *have* written that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You prove this using De-Morgan's law. Since the $\sigma-$algebra is closed under countable unions and under complements, and since by De-Morgan, the complement of the union is the intersection of the complements, then you get that the countable intersection of measurable sets must also be measurable.